# linq query for asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

When selecting to update that is postponing or cancelling  , if the column contains "I" it should return error "cannot update. event already deleted"

public ActionResult Cancel(int ID)
        {
            var events = db.Events.Find(ID);
            return PartialView(events);
        }

```
    //
    // POST: /Events/Delete/5

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Cancel(FormCollection Collection)
    {
        var ID = Collection["Event_ID"];
        int intID = int.Parse(ID);
        var events = db.Events.Find(intID);


        // If OK to Cancel , set status to C

        events.Event_Status = "C";
        if (TryUpdateModel(events))
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            string ConfirmMessage = "Event Successfully Cancelled";
            return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "Admin", new { ConfirmMessage = ConfirmMessage });
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView(events);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question, not easy to understand what you are asking..

Comment: When trying to postpone or cancel , if the column has "I" then i should return error "Cannot Postpone/Cancel. State is already inActive(deleted)"

Comment: Please *update* your question, don't post additional comments to clarify. Also, the code would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, please rephrase your question in the form of a question

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

If you want to throw an error if any of the events are inactive

```
if (events.Contains(e => e.Status.Equals("I"))
    throw new Exception("Error :: Cannot cancel an event that is already inactive");
```

If you want to cancel the rest of the events, and warn about the invalid ones:

```
var invalidEvents = events.Where(e => e.Status.Equals("I")).ToList();
var validEvents = events.Where(e => !invalidEvents.Contains(e)).ToList();

// update valid events

var summary = new { Successes = validEvents, Failures = invalidEvents };

return View(summary);
```

You want to make the anonymous type a ViewModel so you don't have to cast but you get the general idea. Also, you should probably filter out the invalid events from the list that you generate to cancel them in the first place to avoid this situation though.

**PRIOR TO UPDATE:**

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but an example of a linq query to get the inactive records would be something like this:

```
var inactiveRecords = from x in dbContext.Records
                      where x.Status.Equals("I")
                      select x;
```

To throw an error on update of one of these records when "C" or "P" is entered, you would do something like this:

```
var recordToUpdate = inactiveRecords.FirstOrDefault(); 
var input = Console.ReadLine();

if (recordToUpdate.Status.Equals("I") && (input.Equals("C") || input.Equals("P"))
    throw new Exception("Error :: Cannot update status of an inactive record");
```

Really though, you shouldn't be using values like "I", "C", or "P" to determine the status of your record, instead you should create a Status table in your database and create a foreign key on the Id of the status.

Comment: Really sorry  new to Stackoverflow so just learning how to use it . It is for an Events System , If i want to postpone or cancel an event , the code should first check if the Event Status is InActive , if it is Inactive it should return error.

Comment: Its ok. I've updated my answer to better reflect what you're trying to do above based on your clarification.

Comment: Thank u, But is there a way to show a Validation Result instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: Yes, that is what the second example shows.. just create a ViewModel and return it instead of the anonymous type.. or you can return the view with a ViewModel containing the invalid events from the first example, the exception was just an example.

Comment: Thanks, can i also please ask  How do i link 2 tables 

Events[ Event_ID , Hobby_Code] 
Hobbies[Hobby_Code] 
Members[Member_ID,Hobby_Code,Event_ID, Member_Email] 

so that when i sent an email to the member the hobby code's of the Members and Events Table must be equal? I want to link Events and Members.

Comment: Ask it in another question as its unrelated. Also mark this as answer if it solved your problem.